# Selenium Grid sending values to one browser in parallel

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-grid

I'm trying to run selenium in parallel but I'm having some major issues.  One major issue I have is that WebDriver sends all values to one browser then another time it'll work first OK for test then second test it'll not send any values and then another test it may hang on opening.
I've seen people get it to work flawless on YouTube and even thought I've tried everything I can think of its never worked like this for me.
I know the port can be passed in as a parameter and I had this before but I don't think its mandatory.

Here's how I've got everything setup starting with my hub/node setup...

> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar -role hub
>   -maxInstances=10 -maxSession=10 -port 7777 -timeout 29000
>
> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar -role webdriver -hub
>   http://localhost:7777/grid/register  -maxSession=5 -maxInstance=5
>   -port 4441 -timeout 30000 -browser browserName="safari",platform=WINDOWS
>
> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -role webdriver -hub
>   http://localhost:7777/grid/register -port 4448 -timeout 30000 -browser
>   browserName="firefox",platform=WINDOWS,maxSession=5,maxInstances=5

My xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<suite name = "Cross Browser Testing" verbose = "3" parallel = "tests" thread-count="5">
    <test name = "Firefox Test">
    <parameter name = "browser" value ="firefox">
    </parameter>
        <classes>
            <class name = "TestClass.Dashboard"/>
            <class name = "TestClass.Login"/>           
        </classes>
    </test> 

        <test name = "Safari Test">
    <parameter name = "browser" value ="safari">
    </parameter>
        <classes>
            <class name = "TestClass.Dashboard"/>
            <class name = "TestClass.Login"/>           
        </classes>
    </test>     
</suite>
```

Here's how I'm calling my xml

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

public class Launch extends AbstractPage {

    public Launch() {
        super();
    }   

    @BeforeMethod
    @Parameters({"browser"})
    public void launchBrowsers(String browser) throws MalformedURLException {

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        capabilities.setBrowserName(browser);
        capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);

        // To remove message "You are using an unsupported command-line
        // flag: --ignore-certificate-errors.
        // Stability and security will suffer."
        // Add an argument 'test-type'
        ChromeOptions chrome = new ChromeOptions();
        chrome.addArguments("test-type");
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chrome);
        capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary",
                "C:\\location\\chromedriver.exe");

        //setup internet explorer
        capabilities.setCapability("InternetExplorerDriverServer.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION",true);
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",
                "C:\\location\\IEDriverServer.exe");

        selenium = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:7777/wd/hub"), capabilities);

        getSelenium().manage().window().maximize();
        getSelenium().manage().deleteAllCookies();

    }   

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        //close down browser window
        if (selenium == null) {
            try {
                selenium.quit();
                selenium.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried the switch statement

```
switch(browser) {

        case "iexplorer":   
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",
                    "C:\\location\\IEDriverServer.exe");
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities1 = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();             
            selenium = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:7777/wd/hub"), capabilities1); 
            break;

        case "firefox":
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities2 = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();              
            selenium = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:7777/wd/hub"), capabilities2); 
            break;  

        case "safari":
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities3 = DesiredCapabilities.safari();               
            selenium = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:7777/wd/hub"), capabilities3); 
            break;  

        case "chrome":
            System.setProperty("chrome.binary",
                    "C:\\location\\chromedriver.exe");
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();                
            selenium = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:7777/wd/hub"), capabilities);          
            break;  

        default:
            break;
    }
```

Any help to get this working is greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is link [Selenium Grid](http://roadtoautomation.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-run-java-test-scripts-using-grid2.html) to setup and execute selenium test suite using Grid.

I followed it previously and successfully executed.

Comment: Had a look at that and the issues are still the same

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. I was also running two browsers in one node parallel, but whichever browser is initiated first it tries to do all the things in that browser only and in the second browser it does nothing (even the url is not passed into it). As what I did was that in my code the **webdriver was set static** which was causing all the problems so I **removed the static from my webdriver** and tried, then it was working fine.
You just try to declare it public adn then give it a shot. It might work.